# Textarea with one row only won't wrap text inside properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

The problem I've encountered is related to HTML `textarea` and text put there. I want it to have a vertical scroll and to show the text line by line.

Instead it doesn't show the lines properly. For example, let's say I have text that is wrapped into four lines by default. Now let's say I'm at the first line and I hit the scroll down arrow - I will be moved to the third line, another scroll down arrow and I'm at the last, fourth line. Now let's hit arrow up and I'm on the second line. Just as if my scroll didn't recognize the `keyup` event in time, or showing two lines at a time (part of one line and the second line - you can see it if you check the fiddle I'm attaching [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Dz8Lg/)).

Please be aware that this issue occurs only when I choose my `textarea` to be one row only - if I choose two rows everything seems to be working just fine.

**My code:**

```
<html>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
textarea[name="info"] {resize: none; height: 100%; width:100%, 375px; overflow-y: scroll;
    }
</style>
<textarea name="info" cols=65 wrap="soft" rows=1 disabled="disabled">Niewielkie wzniesienie o kształcie kopca, z wyraźnie zaznaczonym wierzchołkiem i łagodnymi zboczami wznosi się nad Mariańską Doliną położoną po wschodniej stronie. Góra wyrasta na końcu ramienia odchodzącego na południowy-zachód od rozrogu. </textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

[Same code put in fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Dz8Lg/)

Here in the fiddle you can see the problem: if the `textarea` would be resized (expanded), you can see four lines of text. However, when you scroll you only have three lines (and the first-click-line is bugged - two lines in one row).

Comment: Add `textarea { line-height: 20px; }` in your fiddle.

Comment: Adding textarea { line-height: 20px; } causes the problem I  wrote about in the beginning - now textarea, when scrolled shows wrong lines. Take a look - line first: "Niewielkie wzniesienie o kształcie kopca, z wyraźnie zaznaczonym", line second (which is in fact third one) - "Doliną położoną po wschodniej stronie. Góra wyrasta na końcu", while line "wierzchołkiem i łagodnymi zboczami wznosi się nad Mariańską" is missing.